# Remove subdirectory & remove .php extention in htaccess not working?

Tags: .htaccess

I m new to url rewrite:

First, here is what I am trying to accomplish:
Current URL: www.example.com/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/something.php

Desired  URL: www.example.com/subdirectory1/something/

And, the name of subdirectory2 is fixed.

Possible?

My current htaccess just to remove the ".php" but also not working. (Any idea how to debug htaccess??)

```
RewritEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(?!subdirectory1/|subdirectory2/)(.+)$ subdirectory1/$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is `RewritEngine on`. You are missing an e. Should be `RewriteEngine on`.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/fixed/([^/]+).php$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "friendly" URL into php.
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/fixed/$2.php [L]
```

This only works for **exactly** what you said. Fixed is always the same. Replace it with the correct value.

The users goes to: `www.example.com/1234/fixed/5678.php`. He is redirected to `www.example.com/1234/5678`

User goes to `www.example.com/1234/5678`. On the server, this becomes `www.example.com/1234/fixed/5678.php`.

Something like `www.example.com/1234/5678/9abcd` will not work. (More than two levels of directories.)

Comment: i got 404 error. i did change the value "fixed" to my exact value which is called "controllers".

Comment: I made an error. I wrote `([^/])+` in several places but it should be `([^/]+)`. I have edited the post. Try now.

Comment: Is the site online anywhere so I can look?

Comment: not yet online, but i just upload to a test server. i need few more seconds to upload the htaccess... give me a sec. ;) http://www.ohmygoh.com/jason/controllers/home.php

Comment: I will go to bed now, but before I go, the .htaccess file should be in the root folder. `RewriteBase /` shouldn't matter, but you can always try it.

Comment: If you can't put in the root, you can move the whole structure to the jason folder. `http://www.ohmygoh.com/jason/something/controllers/something.php` and put the .htaccess in jason. Good luck for now.

Comment: it is in the jason folder. Anyway, i will wait someone to help me... :) thanks.